# "if" condition variable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am building a quiz app, working fine now decided to add "boosters" (help tools for the player), I've already posted a question here about adding extra time to the timer, I am still digging to find a solution, but no luck til now.. Anyway, this is not my question now.
I started to work on the second booster: Successfully skip a question (without losing points)

So the original code (before adding the boost part) was like this:

```
<div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
     <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>">
          <?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $result['question_name'];?></p>
               <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' 
                     name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>
               <?php echo $result['answer1'];?><br/>
               <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' 
                     name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>
               <?php echo $result['answer2'];?><br/>
               <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' 
                      name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>
               <?php echo $result['answer3'];?><br/>
               <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' 
                      name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>
               <?php echo $result['answer4'];?><br/>
               <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" 
                      id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' 
                         name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/><br/>
               <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='button' >Next</button>
```

And this is how the points are count:

```
if(isset($_POST[1])){ 
$keys=array_keys($_POST);
$order=join(",",$keys);

//$query="select * from questions id IN($order) ORDER BY FIELD(id,$order)";
// echo $query;exit;

$response=mysql_query("select id,answer from questions where id IN($order) ORDER BY   FIELD(id,$order)")   or die(mysql_error());
$right_answer=0;
$wrong_answer=0;
$unanswered=0;
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($response)){
   if($result['answer']==$_POST[$result['id']]){
           $right_answer++;
       }else if($_POST[$result['id']]==5){
           $unanswered++;
       }
       else{
           $wrong_answer++;
       }

}
```

So my idea was about adding a button called "Success skipe"

```
<button id='<?php echo $success;?>' class='skip btn btn-success' type='button'>Success Skip</button>
```

And while counting the right answers I tried to make a condition that once this button is clicked the answer is considered correct so I added this:

```
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($response)){
if($success){                          //Just added
$right_answer++;                   //this "if" condition
}
```

But it didn't work, what's wrong?

Comment: `$success` never gets set in the code you provided.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I forget to mention that I put $success=1; in the beginning of the code.
I get no error, just when displaying the result that skipped question doesn't count, it behave just like I have clicked "next" without answering (so no point for that question)

Comment: You are missing `}` in while loop at the end.

Comment: It's not missing just I didn't copy the whole code `while($result=mysql_fetch_array($response)){
   if($success){
 $right_answer++;
   }
       if($result['answer']==$_POST[$result['id']]){
               $right_answer++;
           }else if($_POST[$result['id']]==5){
               $unanswered++;
           }
           else{
               $wrong_answer++;
           }
       
   }
   
   
   echo "right_answer : ". $right_answer."<br>";
   echo "wrong_answer : ". $wrong_answer."<br>";
   echo "unanswered : ". $unanswered."<br>";
}`